# Why does Kinect2 Fusion produce worst results, then Kinect1?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

At my university we have several Kinect 1's and Kinect 2's. I am testing the quality of the Kinect Fusion results on both device and unexpectedly Kinect 2 produces worst results.

My testing environment:

- Static camera scanning a static scene.

In this case if I check both results from Kinect 1 and 2, then it looks like Kinect 2 has a way smoother and nicer resulting point cloud, but if I check the scans from a different angle, then you can see the that Kinect 2 result is way worst even if the point cloud is smoother. As you can see on the pictures if I check the resulting point cloud from the same view as the camera was, then it looks nice, but as soon as I check it from a different angle then the Kinect 2 result is horrible, can't even tell that in the red circle there is a mug.

[image]
[image]

- Moving camera scanning a static scene

In this case Kinect 2 has even worst results, then in the above mentioned case compared to Kinect 1. Actually I can't even reconstruct with Kinect 2 if I am moving it. On the other hand Kinect 1 does a pretty good job with moving camera.

Does anybody have any idea why is the Kinect 2 failing these tests against Kinect 1? As I mentioned above we have several Kinect cameras at my university and I tested more then one of them each, so this should not be a hardware problem.

Comment: There is a discussion about this here also: http://www.pcl-users.org/Obtaining-a-point-cloud-with-Kinec1-vs-Kinect2-td4037069.html#a4037169

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar results when I was using Kinect for 3D reconstruction. Kinect 2 produced worse results compared to Kienct 1. In fact, I tried the InfiniTAM framework for doing 3D reconstruction. It too yielded similar results. What was different in my case compared to yours was that I was moving the camera around and the camera tracking was awful.

When I asked the authors of InfiniTAM about this, they provided the following likely explanation:

> ... the Kinect v2 has a time of flight camera rather than a structured
>   light sensor. Due to imperfections in the modulation of the active
>   illumination, it is known that most of these time of flight sensors
>   tend to have biased depth values, e.g. at a distance of 2m, everything
>   is about 5cm closer than measured, at a distance of 3m everything is
>   about 5cm further away than measured...

Apparently, this is not an issue with structured light cameras (Kinect v1 and the like). You can follow the original discussion [here](https://github.com/victorprad/InfiniTAM/issues/33).